# Failed to assign value to a variable in bash -c "commands;"

Tags: bash

I've tried the following ways to assign s value to a variable and print it:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ bash -c "variable=1111; echo $variable"

user@ubuntu:~$ bash -c "variable=1111; echo $variable > output"
user@ubuntu:~$ cat output

user@ubuntu:~$ bash -c "variable=1111 && echo $variable"

user@ubuntu:~$ bash -c "variable=1111 && echo $variable > output"
user@ubuntu:~$ cat output

user@ubuntu:~$
```

But as you see, in all the situations I failed to print 1111 in the output. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply:  Use single quotes.

```
bash -c 'variable=1111; echo $variable'
```

The quotes are meaningful to the shell.  Double quotes escape spaces and globs (roughly speaking, * expansion). but still allow for string interpolation.  Single quotes do the same as double quotes, but they also escape the `$`.

Comment: Thank you. What does "escape" means here? It means "translate" or "leave it as it is"?

Comment: Escape means leave it as it is.  The idea is to pass the literal `$variable` to the bash executable.   If you don't escapee it, the current shell will replace the `$variable` with a nothing and pass `variable=1111; echo` to the bash program.  Another way of writing this code is to explicitly escape the `$` like this:  `bash -c "variable=1111; echo \$variable"`